# Could I say the more the thickness is, the greater the A is?

Tags: grammaticality

The resistor formula is R=ρL/A.
Is this sentence grammatically wrong about *the more...is...the greater...is*?

*Total length of resistive element is like L in the formula. The thickness of film layer is like A, the more the thickness is, the greater the A is.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, I'm an electrical engineer and recognize sheet-rho calculations.

In my experience, the statement would be better said as...

> As thickness increases, resistance decreases.

It would be odd to say "as thickness increases, A increases" because variable "A" represents the thickness.  It would be the same as saying, "as A increases, A increases" or "as the thickness increases, the thickness increases."

Many years ago, one of the ladies helping a group of us develop the world's first electronic databooks made a useful statement, "don't tell us red is red because it's red."  That seems very obvious (indeed, it is very obvious), but we ran into that problem frequently while trying to describe the [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) for the databooks.  I believe you're falling into the same trap because you're forgetting that, in application, there's no difference between the thickness of the film and the symbol meant to identify that thickness.  When resolved, they both have the same identifying number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and professional explaining^_^